# Unit tests don't use the same path as by web app in debug

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When debugging my app, my app uses 'http://localhost:63595/', but when I run a test, it only uses 'http://localhost/'. The problem I run into is this, I'm trying to load an .xslt file. My code looks like this:

```
var currentWebPath = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
//....
objxslt.Load(currentWebPath + "/XSLT/Email/" + templateName + ".xslt");
```

This works at runtime, but not during the test.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Are you sure you want to load a file via `http` in your unit test? Anyways, the `http://localhost:63595` url seems to be a visual studio development server link. This can change.

Comment: I'd like to test the loading of the xslt if possible. I guess I would need to load it one way or another.

Comment: It is not good to have unit tests depend on *anything* external. This makes them prone to breaking and possibly hard to use by other developers. If other developers can't use your tests, then they may just ignore them altogether. I suggest you rethink your test. You don't need to test `objxslt.Load()` because it is not part of your code, and Microsoft likely already has tests to cover it. The line that occurs after this one might be a different story, but you should use some sort of fake to mimic the transformation.

Comment: I'm not trying to test objxslt.Load(), just the code that happens to have that as one of it's parts. Do you have an example of the fake for loading XSLT?